# I want to formulate a new object using replication

Tags: r

I have a string of values;

```
a <- 1:159
```

and I want to formulate a new object that which first writes a sequence from 80:159 and second 79:158 and third 78:157.....up to 1:80. I want this new object to have 6400 elements.

I tried to use

```
for (i in rep(1:80,each=80)){a[i] <- ((81-i):(160-i))}
```

which is not working.

Comment: A good starting place, if you know that the final object will be an integer vector of length 6400, you should create it ahead of time: `myVector <- integer(6400)`. Then you can fill it in. This wil save R a lot of effort in repeatedly copying a growing object.

Comment: `unlist(lapply(80:1, function(x){seq(x, length.out = 80)}))`, maybe

Answer (score 3):

You can just use

```
x <- embed(a, 80)
```

The columns will correspond to what you want

```
x[,1] == 80:159
x[,2] == 79:158
...
x[,80] == 1:80
```

and

```
length(x)
# 6400
```

and if you just want it as a vector rather than a matrix, just do

```
x <- as.vector(embed(a, 80))
```